# Bugzilla report bug using PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, bugzilla

I was trying to post a bug to my bugzilla account using this code

```
set_time_limit(0);
    $URI = 'http://site.com/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi';
    $xml_data = array(
    'login' => 'email',
    'password' => 'password',
    'remember' => 0
    );
    $bug_ids = array(50, 100);  // bugs list
    //$file_cookie = tempnam('', 'bugzilla-cookie');
        $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        //CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_URL     => $URI,
        CURLOPT_POST    => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array( 'Content-Type: text/xml', 'charset=utf-8' )
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("User.login", $xml_data);
    var_dump($request); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file_cookie);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch); // Array( [id] => 1 ) for example
    print_r ($server_output);


    $response = xmlrpc_decode($server_output);
```

But it keep requesting and i get no response

Also I read the Documentation of the BugZilla and I got nothing from it

Also I found a code for Zend framework

```
$oClient = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://my.zilla.url/xmlrpc.cgi');

$oHttpClient = new Zend_Http_Client();
$oHttpClient->setCookieJar();
$oClient->setHttpClient($oHttpClient);

$aResponse = $oClient->call('User.login', array(array(
    'login'    => 'peterh@mydomain.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'remember' => 1
)));

$aResponse = $oClient->call('Bug.create', array(array(
    'product'     => "My Product",
    'component'   => "My Component",
    'summary'     => "This is the summary of the bug I'm creating",
    'version'     => "unspecified",
    'description' => "This is a description of the bug",
    'op_sys'      => "All",
    'platform'    => "---",
    'priority'    => "P5",
    'severity'    => "Trivial"
)));
$iBugId = $aResponse['id'];

$aResponse = $oClient->call('User.logout');
```

But I am not using Zend framework

And there is also some perl files as I read but I don't know how to deal with them

After three days of searching and reading I came here 
Please Help me to accomplish it

Comment: What do you mean by `i get no response`? There's always a response. What HTTP response code do you recieve? Does the curl have any error? Try this after curl_exec: `echo "Error CURL: " . curl_error($ch) . " Error number: " . curl_errno($ch);`r

Answer (score 3):

i  create bug in bugzilla using this code ...i hope this is helpful to someone

```
set_time_limit(0);
$URI = 'your bugzilla url/xmlrpc.cgi';
$xml_data = array(
    'login' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'remember' => 0
);
$ch = curl_init();
$file_cookie = tempnam('', 'bugzilla-cookie');
$options = array(
        //CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_URL     => $URI,
        CURLOPT_POST    => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array( 'Content-Type: text/xml', 'charset=utf-8' )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("User.login", $xml_data);
//  var_dump($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file_cookie);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch); // Array( [id] => 1 ) for example

print_r ($server_output);
echo "<br />";

$response = xmlrpc_decode($server_output);

print_r ($response);

$xml_data1 = array(
        'product'     => "Magento",
        'component'   => "Menu",
        'summary'     => "this is third testing bug",
        'assigned_to' => "assigneename",
        'version'     => "1.6.2.0",
        'description' => "This is a description of the bug",
        'op_sys'      => "All",
        'platform'    => "All",
        'priority'    => "Normal",
        'severity'    => "Trivial"
);


$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("Bug.create", $xml_data1); // create a request for filing bugs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

$response = xmlrpc_decode(curl_exec($ch));


print_r ($response);
```

Comment: Mayur, when I execute your code sample, I get the following error. Please help token1-TqsDDzDIH0id1
Array ( [token] => 1-TqsDDzDIH0 [id] => 1 ) Array ( [faultString] => You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla. [faultCode] => 410 )

Answer (score 0):

This following documentation focus on how to create a XML-RPC Server, but at the end shows a sample for consuming the generated XML-RPC service.

[the Bakery - How to create an XML-RPC server with CakePHP](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/filippo.toso/2008/11/15/how-to-create-an-xml-rpc-server-with-cakephp)

The class may be helpful, since you need someway to connect to a XML-RPC server (bugzilla)